# Why is the surface tension of copper and cadmium in molten state increases with increase in temperature while it decrease for other liquids?

Tags: fluid-statics, surface-tension

Recently, I saw a question in my exam regarding surface tension. It was mentioned in the answer key that the surface tension of copper and cadmium in the molten state increases with an increase in temperature. In contrast, the surface tension of other liquids continuously decreases with an increase in temperature. Why is this happening?

Comment: Cross posted here: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/172583/79678.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If we adapt the [Gibbs free energy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gibbs_free_energy) $G$ to include surface tension–surface area ($\sigma$–$A$) work, we could work with the potential

$$\Pi=G-\sigma A;$$
$$d\Pi=-S\,dT+V\,dP-A\,d\sigma,$$

with entropy $S$, temperature $T$, volume $V$, and pressure $P$. At equilibrium at constant pressure, we have

$$S\,dT=-A\,d\sigma;$$
$$\frac{d\sigma}{dT}=-\frac{S}{A},$$

indicating that the temperature dependence of the surface tension depends on the entropy per unit area of the surface relative to the bulk.

It has thus been argued (e.g., by [White](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF02642581)) that the surface atoms of cadmium, copper and zinc, for example, have a higher degree of order at the surface (and thus a negative relative entropy), resulting in the surface tension increasing with increasing temperature over that range.

However, [Nogi](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF02670829) later reported based on their sessile-drop and levitated-drop surface tension measurements that this positive $\frac{d\sigma}{dA}$ is an artifactual result of impurities (e.g., oxygen, water vapor) interacting with the drop. In general, we expect the surface tension of liquids to decrease with increasing temperature.

(As a side note, I wouldn't trust anything found in IIT JEE preparatory materials—this site has many examples of questions based on confusion from incorrect IIT JEE content.)

Comment: Thank you...... and how did you find that this is from IIT JEE mock test ??

Comment: Just an online search for the keywords.